# get more MIME types for phpmyadmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, mime-types

I want to work with uploading pdf files. I found out the mime type to be used for pdf files is

```
application/pdf
```

but the phpmyadmin I am using currently displays only following MIME types

```
Applicatiion/Octstream
Image/JPEG
Image/PNG
Text/Plain
```

How do I upload pdf and other file types in the database?
Is mime type required for all?
what is the standard procedure to update or add MIME types??

[image]

Comment: You want to upload a PDF file inside a table? inside a column? Please clarify?

Comment: What does this have to do with phpMyAdmin ? Just make the column type `BLOB`, it doesn't need any mime type. Perhaps you should add a screenshot so we know what youre talking about.

Comment: @DanFromGermany in case you are not aware, phpMyAdmin supports MIME types for output and input transformation of data.

Comment: @PiyushVishwakarma do you wish to upload a PDF file inside a table or inside a column?

Comment: inside a column column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload a .pdf file inside a column via phpMyAdmin, you don't need to have a MIME type set for this column. You just need to define the column as a LONGBLOB for example, and in the Insert panel, you'll be able to upload into it.

The MIME type has to be defined if you want to display this PDF while browsing the table. This is documented in http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/transformations.html but you have to code a transformation for it.